# 'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'

Tags: azure

I am developing 1 web app for Azure by PHP.
When i deploy this app to Azure by Azure CLI

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group gaoResourceLinux --name gaoExtDBApp3 --src clouddrive/sqltest.zip
```

It meet error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 194, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py", line 319, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py", line 292, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/init.py", line 169, in call
    return super(AzCliCommand, self).call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 109, in call
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/init.py", line 337, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 1605, in enable_zip_deploy
    user_name, password = _get_site_credential(resource_group_name, name, slot)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 1240, in _get_site_credential
    creds = _generic_site_operation(resource_group_name, name, 'list_publishing_credentials', slot)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/_appservice_utils.py", line 11, in _generic_site_operation
    client = client or web_client_factory(cli_ctx)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/_client_factory.py", line 35, in web_client_factory
    return get_mgmt_service_client(cli_ctx, WebSiteManagementClient)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/client_factory.py", line 35, in get_mgmt_service_client
    api_version=api_version, sdk_profile=sdk_profile, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/client_factory.py", line 83, in _get_mgmt_service_client
    resource = resource or cli_ctx.cloud.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cloud'
```

Please help me.
Thank.

Comment: Could you please check your CLI version with this command `az --version`? Or are you use Azure cloud shell?

Comment: Yes i am using Azure Cloud Shell <br>
az --version<br>
azure-cli (2.0.25)<br>

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'<br>
Extensions directory '/home/nguyen/.azure/cliextensions'<br>

Python (Linux) 3.6.1 (default, Jan 12 2018, 17:31:35)<br>
[GCC 4.8.4]<br>

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal<br>